# What's the name of this battery connector?

Tags: connector, components, batteries

Been trying to find this "battery bridge" as a spare part to old virtual pets. It's like cell battery connector, but it's individual part connecting two cell batteries (LR44), which has their other plus and minus connectors on circuit board. I have no idea is this something that is still made.

This part usually gets ruined because of corrosion if old batteries are left inside device. Would need replacement ones, but can't find real name for this part.

[image]

Comment: Search Mouser or Digikey for "coin cell holders". There is no specific name for that style since there are many ways you can retain an LR44 coincell, but you can go by  photos, then datasheet measurements of dimensions.

Comment: Also, check Keystone: https://www.keyelco.com/  They make all sorts of metal contacts for batteries and such.

Comment: Most likely it's a custom piece of bent metal. But you might get lucky and find a close enough alternative as suggested in other comments.

Comment: You might like to DIY your own "bridge", from components of this: LR44 Battary Holder Online Catalog - AliExpress:
https://www.aliexpress.com/w/wholesale-lr44-battery-holder.html. Good luck. Cheers.

Comment: This looks like yours. https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/4000273998684.html?spm=a2g0o.search0302.0.0.46ef5592mJGyPK&algo_pvid=60bd44a3-a671-4ef2-819d-d9d7f42acce8&algo_expid=60bd44a3-a671-4ef2-819d-d9d7f42acce8-4&btsid=0b0a555516170655459044886e1db1&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_. Or you might consider those with extension wires for you to "bridge" to other batteries. Cheers.